# Is using water in a charcoal smoker less efficient than not using water?

Tags: thermodynamics, conservation-laws

I have a charcoal smoker that uses water.  My understanding is that the water serves as a buffer and as a way to add moisture to the cooking environment.  Some say that using water wastes fuel because you have to heat the water.

If I am applying Newton's Conservation Law correctly, it seems to me that the heat put into the water is also released from the water as heat energy which also heats the food.  So, I don't see that as wasteful.  Is more energy lost in that part of the process than if no water was used?

It seems to me that the only waste is the heat left in the water after you are finished cooking.  If you start with hot water from the tap, there's even less heat wasted there.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds about right. You could even boil the water before u put it in the smoker then all the smoker has to do is maintain the temp of the water as it cools.

Comment: It would still need to supply the energy needed to boil the water (enthalpy of vaporization).